# Win32Clipboard.GetClipboardData - Formatting

Tags: python, pywin32

I have the following code to read the data from the clipboard and add it to a database:

```
    import win32clipboard, sqlite3
try:
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    print data[0] # testing
    print data[1] # testing
    test = ''.join(data)
    print test

    conn = sqlite3.connect('DB')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Clipboard (Data) VALUES (?)', (test))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


except TypeError as e:
    pass
    print e
```

As an example, the clipboard data is "stackoverflow".
The following error is received:

```
 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
t
stackoverflow
  File "clipboard.py", line 13, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Clipboard (Data) VALUES (?)', (test))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 13 supplied.
```

I assumed that the output of the "data" was in a tuple or list. So i tried to join the values in multiple ways, the above join only represents one of the ways that was tested.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter list must be a sequence.
You send string - sqlite reading it as sequence of a letters.
Just add comma `(test,)` to send tuple with one element or use a list `[test]`.

Comment: Ah perfect. Thanks. Can you give me a brief overview of why this needs to happen or what search term would be best for researching myself? Just looking at Tuples brings up a hell of a lot!!!

Comment: Tuple is like a list.  
Only two differences: tuple is immutable and require less memory than list.  
List denoted by a square brackets, tuple by a round brackets.  
Comma at the end of tuple with one element serve for understanding where is tuple and where is simply logical brackets.